# Multiple keys in sendKeys action

Tags: dalekjs

I'm trying to pass multiple keys `Cmd Alt P` at the same time to Dalek to test page behavior:

```
test
    .open('themes/ribbon/index.html')
    .sendKeys('body', '\uE03D\uE00A\u0050') // Cmd Alt P
    .assert.attr('body', 'class', 'full')
.done();
```

And it seems doesn't work as test is failing. I'm using [W3C WebDriver spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/#character-types) for key codes reference, but I haven't found clear description on how to send multiple keys (both in Dalek docs and spec), especially with regular, not special ones like Alt and Cmd.

The same test with just a `F5` works fine, of course:

```
test
    .open('themes/ribbon/index.html')
    .sendKeys('body', '\uE035') // F5
    .assert.attr('body', 'class', 'full')
.done();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test I came to the conclusion that this is related to a bug in DalekJS, could you please go over to [Github](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/issues?state=open) and file an issue there?!

Thanks.